# Pandas groupby, find match and write back to column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In the dataframe *data*, I want to groupby 'Name', find where "Price1" and "Price2" are equal and then write the values in 'answer' to a new column with respect to groupby 'Name'. ex:

```
d = {
    'Name': ['Cat', 'Cat', 'Dog', 'Dog'],
    'Price1': [2, 1, 10, 3],
    'Price2':[5,1,7,3],
    'answer':['A','B','C','D']
}

data = pd.DataFrame(data=d) 

    Name Price1 Price2 Answer
0   Cat   2     5      A
1.  Cat   1     1      B        <--- match, get 'B'
2.  Dog   10    7      C
3.  Dog   3     3      D        <---- match, get 'D'
```

something like this

```
data['result'] = data.groupby('itemName')['answer'] where [data['Price1']=data['Price2'] #<---- this is the part I need equation.
```

and expect 2nd (1=1) and 4th (3&3) rows each match and lookup 'answer' column 'B' and 'D', so result is:

```
data['result'] 
0   'B'
1   'B'
2   'D'
3   'D'
```

I've tried something like this

```
data.groupby('itemName')['Price1'].transform(x:data['answer'][x==data['Price2']],
```

which gives error

> ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects

and tried this not even using x.

```
data.groupby('itemName')['Price1'].transform(x:data['answer'][data['Price1']==data['Price2']],
```

result only applies to the matched indices:

```
data['result'] 
0   NaN
1   'B'
2   NaN
3   'D'
```

I think I am close but missing the key concept.

Comment: What if there is no match or multiple matches?

Comment: thats a good exercise too. For my case there will always be one and only one match per group.

Answer (score 4):

IIUC,

```
df.loc[df['Price1'] == df['Price2'], 'result'] = df['answer']
df['result'] = df.groupby('Name')['result'].transform('first')
print(df)
```

Output:

```
  Name  Price1  Price2 answer result
0  Cat       2       5      A      B
1  Cat       1       1      B      B
2  Dog      10       7      C      D
3  Dog       3       3      D      D
```

Comment: You can't use transform when access two columns.  Hence, I build the results of two columns first then transform off those results.

Comment: That's the way to go! Note that you could directly use `where` and `groupby` on it to avoid setting the intermediate column ;)

Comment: This is clever and clean! :) works well, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do the query and select operation in `groupby.apply`

```py
out = (df.groupby('Name', as_index=False, group_keys=False)
       .apply(lambda df_: df_.assign(result=df_.query('Price1 == Price2').eval('answer').item())))
```

```
print(out)

  Name  Price1  Price2 answer result
0  Cat       2       5      A      B
1  Cat       1       1      B      B
2  Dog      10       7      C      D
3  Dog       3       3      D      D
```